# ¿Existe una palabra en español para el acto o práctica de crear continuamente nuevas palabras?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

¿Hay alguna palabra en español que haga referencia al acto o práctica de estar continuamente creando nuevas palabras?

Hay algunas disciplinas y en particular algunas personas que practican estas disciplinas que están inventando continuamente palabras. ¿Tiene esta acción algun nombre?

Comment: Para definir lo que buscas posiblemente necesites una nueva palabra. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Qué tal **neologismanía**?

Por un lado tenemos:

> **[neologismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QOrQDkR)**
>
> De *neo-*, el gr. *λόγος lógos* 'palabra' e *-ismo*.
>
> 1. m. Ling. Vocablo, acepción o giro nuevo en una lengua.
> 2. m. Ling. Uso de neologismos.

De aquí podríamos decir **neologismear**: crear un neologismo, usando el sufijo *[-ear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EIeaLdH)*. Pero también podríamos usar el sufijo *-manía*:

> **[-manía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OD1nVZ2)**
>
> Del gr. *-μανία -manía*.
>
> 1. elem. compos. Significa 'inclinación excesiva'. *Grafomanía*.
> 2. elem. compos. Significa 'impulso obsesivo' o 'hábito patológico'. *Piromanía, toxicomanía*.
> 3. elem. compos. Significa 'afición apasionada'. *Melomanía*.

Así, *neologismanía* sería "impulso obsesivo (o afición apasionada) por los neologismos".

Comment: Por un lado suena bien , representa la idea que busco, por otro lado "no suena bien" en el sentido que es dificil de pronunciar jaja

Comment: @Pablo Los nombres de manías suelen serlo. Te agradezco la marca de "respuesta aceptada". En todo caso, considera en un futuro dar un tiempo de cortesía para ver si alguien más se anima a responder, y así tener más donde elegir. :-)